# can't dispal 2 garphs on chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

can please someone help me displaying 2 graphs on chart.js?
I'm reading JSON file locally and I want to display 2 graphs.
but unfortunately I can see only one graph...
this is the HTML code:

```
<body>
    <canvas id="graph1" height="500" width="700" />
    <canvas id="graph2" height="300" width="500" />
    <!-- <canvas id="graph3" height="500" width="700" /> -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.2.1/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

this is the JS code:

```
<script>
    $.getJSON("http://localhost/json_for_graph.json", function (result) {
        graph1 = result.dict_for_graph1
        graph2 = result.dict_for_graph2
        var graph1_unique_id = []
        var graph1unknown_list = []
        var graph1_relevant_list = []
        var graph2_all_times = []
        var graph2_id_appear_one_time = []

        for (var i = 0; i < graph1.value_for_unique_id_list.dict_X_and_Y_values_for_unique_id_list.length; i++) {     graph1_unique_id.push(graph1.value_for_unique_id_list.dict_X_and_Y_values_for_unique_id_list[i])        graph1unknown_list.push(graph1.value_for_all_unknown_list.dict_X_and_Y_values_for_unknown_list[i])        graph1_relevant_list.push(graph1.value_for_all_relevant_list.dict_X_and_Y_values_for_relevant_list[i])
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < graph2.all_times.length; i++) {
            graph2_all_times.push(graph2.all_times)
            graph2_id_appear_one_time.push(graph2.id_appear_one_time)
        }
        var canvas1 = document.getElementById("graph1");
        var graphParams1 = {
            type: "scatter",
            data: {
                datasets: [{
                    label: "Time VS all entities",
                    data: graph1_unique_id,
                    borderColor: "red",
                    backgroundColor: "transparent",
                    showLine: false
                },
                {
                    label: "Time VS unknown entities",
                    data: graph1unknown_list,
                    borderColor: "green",
                    backgroundColor: "transparent",
                    showLine: false
                }, {
                    label: "Time VS relevant entities",
                    data: graph1_relevant_list,
                    borderColor: "blue",
                    backgroundColor: "transparent",
                    showLine: false
                }],
            },
            options: {
                maintainAspectRatio: false,
                responsive: false,
                scales: {
                    xAxes: [{
                        type: "time",
                        distribution: "series",
                    }],
                }
            }
        }
        var canvas2 = document.getElementById("graph2");
        var graphParams2 = {
            type: "scatter",
            data: {
                datasets: [{
                    label: "Time VS RSSI of single reception",
                    data: result.dict_for_graph2.id_appear_one_time,
                    borderColor: "red",
                    backgroundColor: "transparent",
                    showLine: false
                },
                ],
            },
            options: {
                maintainAspectRatio: false,
                responsive: false,
                scales: {
                    xAxes: [{
                        type: "time",
                        distribution: "series",
                    }],
                }
            }
        }
        ctx1 = new Chart(canvas1, graphParams1);
        ctx2 = new Chart(canvas2, graphParams2);
    });
</script>
</html>
```

I  can see only the first chart. and I want to see the 2 charts..
can someone please give me a hand?
thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Unlike the `<img>` element, the `<canvas>` element requires a separate closing tag `(</canvas>).`

Try replacing the canvas elements in your code with the below.

```
<canvas id="graph1" height="500" width="700"></canvas>
<canvas id="graph2" height="300" width="500"></canvas>
```